# Sense Hat Gyroscope issues

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gyroscope

I am trying to use the sense hat gyroscope and accelerometer to check the pitch and acceleration of the pi, if this changes dramatically I want the pi to output a fail. However, once I move the pi and then place it back into rest all of the values do not return to a rest position.

Example output

[image]
Below is the code I am using:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()
sense.set_imu_config(False,True,True) # gyro and accel only mag turned off

while True:
    orientation = sense.get_orientation ()
    pitch = orientation['pitch']
    roll = orientation['roll']
    yaw = orientation['yaw']

    pitch = round (pitch,0)
    roll = round (roll,1)
    yaw = round(yaw,2)

    acceleration = sense.get_accelerometer_raw()
    x = acceleration ['x']
    y = acceleration ['y']
    z = acceleration ['z']

    x=round(x,3)
    y=round(y,4)
    z=round(z,5)


    print("pitch={0}, roll={0}, yaw={0}".format(pitch,yaw,roll))
    print("x={0}, y={0}, z{0}".format(x,y,z))

     if 5 <= pitch <= 300 or x > 1 or y > 1 or z > 1.5: 
        sense.show_message("FAIL")
```

Comment: As the indentation in Python is critical, and your code doesn't appear to have any and so is difficult to understand, please edit your question to correct the indents

Comment: sorry, I have edited.

Comment: You probably can't expect the values to return to exactly the original values. Have you calibrated your sensehat (not sure if this affects the noise/drift/repeatability/stability)?

Comment: I don't expect the exact same values but it can be very far out, also if I move the pitch to 100 for an example, it will slowly drift back to 4-5 but only moving 1 degree or less at a time.